# Trouble Aligning Content w/ Bootstrap and CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My mentor wants me to create a site based off a wireframe he sent, but I haven't been able to position the text on these "hero" images.

[image: What the hero image should look like]
[image: What the hero image actually looks like]

It seems like the text is kind of stuck in the right half of the container, which is weird because offsetting them should have shoved them over to the left. <strike>Unless, of course, I did it wrong.</strike>

I didn't do much to it and I'm confused, especially since I used an offset in the same document that's functioning properly. I tried using classes like justify-content-left, but they seemed to hit an invisible wall in the middle of the container.

```
<div class="p-2" id="navigationFilter">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-6">
                        <header class="pt-5">
                            <p>Enjoy peace of mind knowing that you can</p>
                            <h1>Quickly send for help and alert loved ones</h1>
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">Get Started</button>
                        </header>
                    </div><!-- col -->
                </div><!-- row -->
            </div><!-- container -->
        </div><!-- translucent-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `offset-lg-6` class.

> ### Offset classes
>
> Move columns to the right using .offset-md-* classes.
> These classes increase the left margin of a column by * columns. For
> example, .offset-md-4 moves .col-md-4 over four columns.
>
> -- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#offset-classes

Comment: I must be illiterate or maybe my parents dropped me on my head, because I visited that exact site and didn't figure it out x_x Thank you so much!